# Are there any other words for bucket relay バケツリレー?

Tags: word-requests

> 学生たちが荷物をバケツリレー方式で運んでいる。The students are carrying luggage by the bucket relay method.

[image]

## Question

Are there any other Japanese words with the same meaning as バケツリレー?

Comment: Probably バケツリレー is the only common word that refers to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 「リレー（方{ほう}）式{しき}」 and 「ベルトコンベアー（方）式」

These may not always be interchangeable with 「バケツリレー」, but they are more often than not.

I also feel like including 「人間{にんげん}ベルトコンベアー」, which you will hear from time to time.

Comment: Is there any pure Japanese word for this? :-)

Comment: If you mean a 大和言葉 counterpart, no, I have no idea if there is one.  「順繰り手渡し」 might come kinda close, but the 「順」 part is clearly from Chinese.